# Compare equality of instances of a class with private property

Tags: javascript, lodash

How to make a class with private properties so lodash `isEqual` returns false when comparing any 2 instances with different items in the private properties?

For example, in the following code `isEqual` comparison of the 2 instances of the Bobcat class with different items results in `true`. I want to have `false`. Is there any Map method missing or anything?

```js
const _ = require('lodash')

class Bobcat {
  #items;

  constructor() {
    this.#items = new Map()
  }

  set(key, value) {
    return this.#items.set(key, value)
  }

  get(key) {
    return this.#items.get(key)
  }

  has(key) {
    return this.#items.has(key)
  }

  delete(key) {
    return this.#items.delete(key)
  }

  clear() {
    this.#items.clear()
  }

  keys() {
    return this.#items.keys()
  }

  values() {
    return this.#items.values()
  }

  entries() {
    return this.#items.entries()
  }

  forEach(callbackFn, thisArg) {
    return this.#items.forEach(callbackFn, thisArg)
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this.#items[Symbol.iterator]()
  }
}

const cat1 = new Bobcat()
cat1.set('a', 1)

const cat2 = new Bobcat()
cat2.set('a', 2)

console.log(_.isEqual(cat1, cat2))
// true
```

Another requirement is to have the comparison outside of the class. No comparison method should be added to the class itself. For example, I don't want

```js
class Bobcat {
  isEqual(otherCat) {
    ... 
  }
}
```

or any specific to lodash functionality like

```js
class Bobcat {
  [Symbol.for('lodash.isEqual')](otherCat) {
    ... 
  }
}
```

Comment: Private properties are completely encapsulated and *only* reachable from inside the class. There is no way to read them otherwise. So, having an external comparison that tries to take them into account won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Customizing `toStringTag` to return `Map` solves the issue for me without changing the downstream code on the isEqual comparison.

```js
  get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
    return 'Map'
  }
```

Entire code

```js
const _ = require('lodash')

class Bobcat {
  #items

  constructor() {
    this.#items = new Map()
  }

  set(key, value) {
    return this.#items.set(key, value)
  }

  get(key) {
    return this.#items.get(key)
  }

  has(key) {
    return this.#items.has(key)
  }

  delete(key) {
    return this.#items.delete(key)
  }

  clear() {
    this.#items.clear()
  }

  keys() {
    return this.#items.keys()
  }

  values() {
    return this.#items.values()
  }

  entries() {
    return this.#items.entries()
  }

  forEach(callbackFn, thisArg) {
    return this.#items.forEach(callbackFn, thisArg)
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this.#items[Symbol.iterator]()
  }

  get size() {
    return this.#items.size
  }

  get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
    return 'Map'
  }
}

const cat1 = new Bobcat()
cat1.set('a', 1)

const cat2 = new Bobcat()
cat2.set('a', 1)

// true
console.log('equal1', _.isEqual(cat1, cat2))

cat2.set('a', 2)

// false
console.log('equal2', _.isEqual(cat1, cat2))
```

Comment: This only works for map-like classes. Not for all classes with private properties. In particular the class should include a `.forEach()` method which Lodash would use. So you could, in theory, have a class with private properties and a `.forEach()` that just lists them, however, that effectively the same as 1. *exposing* the values of the private values (without allowing writes to them)  2. having a custom equality comparison method in the class. OK, it's not exactly "a comparison method" but it still is required whereas the class might not need it. It's not an external thing.